# How are Team Projects mapped to source code in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I just asked a similar question, but this time it's a bit different. I just tried to create a alert in TFS2013 for failed builds and in the query definition next to "Team Project = " there's a dropdown where I'm supposed to pick the project to notify when a checkin happens that breaks the build, but not all of my projects show up there. So where does this list come from? And how come not all of my projects are there?

Answer (score 1):

This may due to you don't have related permission to create alert for some team projects.

> **Alert permissions**
>
> - Members of the team project level **Contributors** group can subscribe to    alerts for themselves.
> - Members of the **Project Collection Administrators** group, or users who    have the **Edit collection-level information** can set
>     alerts in that    collection for others or for a team.
> - Members of the **Project Administrators** group, or users who have the    **Edit project-level information** can set alerts in that team
>     project    for others or for a team.

You may lack of the  corresponding permission for several team projects. So you could not select those in the dropdown list.

**Note:** *There are no UI permissions associated with managing email notifications or alerts. Instead, they can be managed using the [TFSSecurity command line tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#collection-level-permissions).*

More details about this you could refer this MSDN thread: **[Alert permissions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#alert-permissions)**